# Destructuring in JavaScript while using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came up with the following questing while I was trying to make a TODO app using React.js
I was trying to make and update functionality for each task. For that, I made a button which on click, calls a function "update" which calls a function passed as a prop defined in App.js, this function iterates through the tasks array find the one to modify and does its thing, then it sets the new state

**App.js**

```
function App() {
      const [taskItems, settaskItems] = useState([]);
      const updateTask = (task,newname) =>{
    const findAndModify=()=>{
      let tasks = [...taskItems] // Why let task=taskItems doesnt work?
      for (let index = 0; index < tasks.length; index++) {
        const t = tasks[index];
        if (t.name === task.name){
          t.name = newname
        }
      }
      return tasks
    }
    settaskItems(findAndModify())
  }
}
```

My TaskRow component is the following

```
<TaskRow task={task} key={task.id} toggleTask={toggleTask} updateTask={updateTask}></TaskRow>
```

Inside the definition of my **TaskRow.js** component I have the following code

```
export const TaskRow = (props) => {       
           const update = () => {
               const newname = "hello";
               props.updateTask(props.task, newname);
                };
                return (
    <tr key={props.task.id}>
      <td>{props.task.name}</td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={props.task.done}
          onChange={() => props.toggleTask(props.task)}
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button className="btn btn-success mx-1" onClick={update}>
          Actualizar
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};
```

the question comes here, if in *findAndModify* instead of doing  *let tasks = [...taskItems]* I do *task=taskItems* the description of the updated task does not re-render until another change happens, but if a do a console.log of the data, it indeed, had been modified
**why is that? how does the [...] operator differs of a regular variable assignment?**
I've researched about destructuring in JS but nobody talks about some kind of difference between the use of this operator and a regular var assignment in React.js

Answer (score 2):

The difference between:
(1) method:

```
let tasks = [...takItems];
```

(2) method:

```
tasks = taksItems
```

is the behavior of javascript with Objects type (for ex. Array)
when you assign a variable to an array it creates a reference and not a shallow copy.

So if you use the (2) method and change tasks variable, it will be reflected in tasksItems, if you use the (1) method, you will have 2 independence variables!

React indicates to NEVER mutate a state directly, like you did when using the (2) method and treat it as immutable type.

You can read more about it here

[Why we should never update React state directly](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/why-we-should-never-update-react-state-directly-c1b794fac59b)

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little bit more, the spread operator `[...takItem]` makes a shallow copy, which means that it will be a new copy of the variable, but because it is 'shallow' any nested non-primitive data will all be pointers. E.g.,

```
const tasks = ['a', 'b', { subtask: 1 }]
const shallowCopy = [...tasks]

shallowCopy[0] = 'A'; // won't change the value of tasks
shallowCopy[2].subtasks = 'C'; // does change the values of tasks

console.log(tasks) 
// ['a', 'b', 'C']
```

In the example above, the third item in the `tasks` array is non-primitive (also known as "reference" type), so `shallowCopy[2]` is just a pointer to the same place in memory as `tasks[2]`. `tasks[2]` and `shallowCopy[2]` are both referencing the same piece of data, which is why when you modify `shallowCopy[2].subtasks` it also modifies `tasks[2].subtasks`